# Delphi visualizers have disappeared

Tags: debugging, delphi

In Delphi 10.2, for some reason I'm no longer seeing the debugging visualizers (i.e. when stopped at a breakpoint in the debugger, if I fly the mouse over a variable, the value(s) of that variable is displayed in a popup.)  I've dug through the main and project options and haven't found any option to turn those on/off, though I may have missed something.  Is there some means of controlling this I'm missing?  (Yes, all the debug symbol stuff is turned on.)

Comment: Have blue dots disappeared just for some lines of code or for all?

Comment: The blue dots (debug line indicators) all display appropriately.  Everything else works - I can put the cursor on a variable, hit Ctrl-F4 and get the Evaluate/Modify dialog to see the contents of the var, for example - but the popup visualizer has gone away.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. When you hove your mouse over variavle it value is **not shown** as expected. But status of variables is shown property in watch list window or in Evaluate/Modiffy dialog.

Comment: Sometimes it just a matter of closing and reopening the IDE, then do a project build, but from your question I gather its permanent.

Comment: Jan - The problem survives reboots, much less IDE restarts. :(

Comment: SilverWarior - Correct.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has resolved itself.  I have no idea why.

Comment: It seems to come and go as it pleases. Sometimes the visualisers load and sometimes they don't. I'd say it's a Delphi bug (at least in Delphi 10.2). There are so many little annoyances with Delphi RAD Studio (all the versions that I've used) and it does become wearying after a while.